Why $SU(N)$ and not $U(N)$?
I am going through one example where they introduce the lagrangian density
\begin{equation}
L(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^N \partial^\mu \phi_i^* \partial_\mu \phi_i - m^2 \phi_i^* \phi_i = \partial^\mu \Phi^\dagger \partial_\mu \Phi - m^2 \Phi^\dagger \Phi,
\end{equation}
where they consider the local gauge transformation $\Phi(x) \to F(x)\Phi(x)$. However, they state that the symmetry group is $SU(N)$, however I do not get why it is not just $U(N)$? How do they obtain the condition that $det(M) = 1$? What is the physical reasoning?

Who are they? Which page?

First, note that you can decompose $U(N) = SU(N) \times U(1)$. In other words, we can think of $U(N)$ as a combination of $SU(N)$ and a $U(1)$ factor. The reason is that both $U(1)$ and $SU(N)$ are subgroups of $U(N)$, and the generator of the $U(1)$ subgroup (which is proportional to $1$) commutes with all of the generators of the $SU(N)$ subgroup.
Second, at the level of global symmetries, you are correct. The Lagrangian
$$
L = -\partial_\mu \Phi^\dagger \partial^\mu \Phi - V(\Phi^\dagger \Phi)
$$
(where $\Phi$ is an $N$ dimensional complex-valued vector) does have global $SU(N)$ symmetry under which $\Phi \rightarrow M \Phi$ (where $M$ is an $N\times N$ unit-determinant unitary matrix), and a $U(1)$ symmetry under which $\Phi \rightarrow e^{i \theta} \Phi$. So it does have a $U(N)$ global symmetry.
However, you asked about a local symmetry. The above Lagrangian does not have any local symmetries. To promote the local symmetry to a global symmetry, we need to introduce gauge fields $A_\mu^a$ (one associated with every generator), and introduce the gauge covariant derivative
$$
D_\mu \Phi = \partial_\mu \Phi - i g A_\mu^a T^a \Phi
$$
where the $T^a$ form a representations of the generators of the symmetry group.
Now, logically, we have a choice here. Even though we have $U(N)$ global symmetry, we don't need to introduce gauge fields for every generator of $U(N)$. We could consistently choose to only include a gauge field of the $U(1)$ factor, we could choose to only include gauge fields for the $SU(N)$ generators, or we could choose to include both kinds of gauge fields. Relatedly, while a non-Abelian gauge field can only have one universal gauge coupling constant $g$, the Abelian gauge field can have different couplings (aka charges) to each particle it couples to, and the charges aren't generically related to the non-Abelian gauge coupling constant. So, logically, there's nothing wrong with choosing to only promote the $SU(N)$ global symmetry to a local one.
Pedagogically, one reason books tend to focus on $SU(N)$ gauge groups over $U(N)$ gauge groups is simplicity -- the Abelian $U(1)$ factor is fairly trivial to add in, compared to the relative complexity of the $SU(N)$ part. Another reason is that this helps build up to the pattern we see in the Standard Model. For QCD, the gluons form a representation of $SU(3)$. There is no Abelian gauge field associated with color charge -- which corresponds to the observational fact that there are no long range force associated with the strong interactions (since the $U(1)$ Abelian field wouldn't have a mass or asymptotic freedom/confinement). Or, more simply, we observe 8 gluons and not 9. For the electroweak interactions, before spontaneous symmetry breaking there are both $SU(2)$ both and $U(1)$ gauge fields, but the way they couple to fermions is quite different. The $SU(2)$ gauge fields only couple to left-handed fermions, whereas the $U(1)$ gauge fields couple to both right handed and left handed fermions, with a pattern of couplings given in this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge#Definition. Again, the $SU(2)$ piece is the more complicated part here -- the way it couples to fermions breaks parity, you need to understand the Higgs mechanism to understand how the non-Abelian fields get a mass -- and the $U(1)$ factor, while important, is fairly easy to add on if you understand what is going on with $SU(2)$.

First paragraph: $U(N)$ is only a semidirect product of $SU(N)$ and $U(1)$. The $U(1)$ consisting of multiples of the identity intersects nontrivially with $SU(N)$.
